# How are product fields loaded to order WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, custom-fields

There is a lot of interesting articles about [How are checkout fields loaded to WooCommerce](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) but I need to add custom fields on product pages and then add variable values to checkout page and order.

Could I add this fields like in default post type?

If ORDER is custom post type called order_post it is possible but how...

HUGE thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try to add the bellow code to your theme function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_field', 0 );

function add_custom_field() {
global $post;
echo "<div class='prod-code'>Product Code: ";
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Product Code', true );
echo "</div>";
return true;
}
```

and in your style.css add below code

```
.prod-code {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -23px;
right: 20%;
}
```

If it work please confirm !

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesn`t work for me...
I think this hooks could help me:
woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button (to add the fields to the form)
woocommerce_add_cart_item_data (to submit the field data)
woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session (to add the data to the session)
woocommerce_get_item_data (to display the data on the cart page)
woocommerce_add_order_item_meta (to ad it to the order so it shows up in the admin area)

But I cant find any example